# How to apply group by on data frame with neglecting NaN values in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am sorry if this is too simple, but I have searched allot and couldn't find a solution for this problem.

I am populating my data frame (df) as below:

```
weather = pd.read_csv(weather_path)
weather_stn1 = weather[weather['Station'] == 1][['Tavg']]
weather_stn2 = weather[weather['Station'] == 2][['Tavg']]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['xAxis', 'yAxis1', 'yAxis2'])
df['xAxis'] = pd.to_datetime(weather['Date'])
df['yAxis1'] = weather_stn1['Tavg']
df['yAxis2'] = weather_stn2['Tavg']
```

My data frame is as below:

```
     xAxis        yAxis1  yAxis2
0   2009-05-01      53     NaN
1   2009-05-01     NaN      55
2   2009-05-02      55     NaN
3   2009-05-02     NaN      55
4   2009-05-03      57     NaN
5   2009-05-03     NaN      58
```

but I want to have my results as below:

```
     xAxis       yAxis1  yAxis2
0   2009-05-01      53     55
2   2009-05-02      55     55
4   2009-05-03      57     58
```

I have been working on reindexing of weather_stn1 and weather_stn2 and in applying group by but it is not working as I want to do. It ends up with me having nothing at all to display!

How should I approach this problem?

Thanks allot for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I have found the solution myself, in case anyone else gets stuck, it would be helpful.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['xAxis', 'yAxis1', 'yAxis2'])
df['xAxis'] = pd.to_datetime(weather['Date'])
df['yAxis1'] = weather_stn1['Tavg']
df['yAxis2'] = weather_stn2['Tavg']

plot_df = plot_df.groupby(plot_df['xAxis']).mean()

print plot_df.reset_index()
```

Now my output is as:

```
         xAxis  yAxis1  yAxis2
0   2009-05-01      53      55
1   2009-05-02      55      55
2   2009-05-03      57      58
3   2009-05-04      57      60
4   2009-05-05      60      62
5   2009-05-06      63      66
```

That simple it was!

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to do is to pivot the table so that the values in `station` columns become column headers. Try this:

```
df = weather.pivot(index='Date', columns='Station', values='Tavg')
```

If there is no more than one record for each station for each date then you will get what you want, except that the dates will be the index rather than a column. 
You can reset the index and change the column names after if you like.